# Algolia escape character for special character

Tags: java, rest, algolia

One of the values in Algolia has "(" and ")" in it which needs to be queried in filter and facet.

for eg:

```
(category:Book(Engg) OR NOT category:Ebook(Novel) )
```

here `Book(Engg)` and `EBook(Novel)` raises the error as it has bracket in it. How to escape a special character character

Answer (score 0):

Try double-quoting your values:

```
filters: 'category:"Book(Engg)" OR NOT category:"Ebook(Novel)"'
```